# table cell tooltip goes off the screen and is not readable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I've set tooltip for every cell of my table
the problem is on the upper rows of table near the top of screen , tooltip text goes off the screen.
I have tested with title attr and its fine , when you're at the top of screen tooltip text changes position to bottom.
but i can't do any style on title attr...

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var columns = ['RegNo', 'NAAB_CODE', 'NAME', 'ICC', 'LNM', 
    'FM','MILK','FAT', 'PRO', 'SCE', 'PL', 'DPR', 'PTAT', 'UDC','FLC', 
    'TPI', 'SIRE', 'MGS'];

    $('#myTable tbody tr').each(function() {
        var cells = $('td', this);
        var titleArr = cells.map(function(index) {
            return columns[index] + ' : ' + this.innerHTML;
        });
        cells.each(function(index) {
            var finalTooltip = titleArr.filter(function(i) {
                return index !== i;
            });
            $(this).attr('title', finalTooltip.toArray().join('\n'));
        });
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('[title]').tooltip({
        container: 'body',
        content: function () {
            var element = $(this);
            return element.attr('title');
        }
    });
});
```

CSS :

```
.tooltip-inner {
max-width: 200px;
padding: 3px 8px;
color: white;
text-align: left;
background-color: rebeccapurple;
border-radius: 4px;
white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: You just need to read [that documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position)...

Comment: you have to add a code that could reproduce the issue

Comment: i thought it's using bootstrap.css , i didn't included jquery-ui.js
but how did i modify the tooltip without including jquery-ui.js p-p

Comment: Here is the [Bootstrap documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/#options) about options. Try to use `data-placement="bottom"` in the tooltip markup. You need to include [`tether.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.1/js/tether.min.js) since it is a dependency for positionning.